# Missing platform support?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I want to connect an existing PhoneGap application to a newly created mobile service in Azure, but in the dashboard for the service I'm only presented with these three choices for the "Choose A Platform" option:

- Windows Store
- Windows Phone 8
- iOS

Where is Android, HTML/JavaScript, Xamarin and the new PhoneGap option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take that you created a new mobile service using the new .NET backend. For now, the *quickstart (starter) projects* for that platform are only available in the four versions you see there (WinStore C#, WinStore JS, WinPhone 8 C#, iOS Objective-C), and others will be added soon.

However, the backend still supports other platforms (HTML/JS, PhoneGap, Android, Xamarin), it's just that we don't have the starter projects for those in the portal yet. You can take one of the supported ones, download the server project, and create the client project to talk to it.

Again, all supported platforms will get their quickstart projects added soon.

Comment: Carlos, I actually tried connecting a working app that currently uses the node.js back-end to a new .net backend on mobile services. I changed the app key etc. I use Facebook login on the client and pass the token to the server. It doesn't work. I get an internal server back. Any ideas? This works fine with the old back-end. Andy